# How do I get top N distinct rows from a table with several repeated values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table on Microsoft SQL server:

```
NumContr  SeqYear check
111111111   1   -0.50
111111111   2   -0.30
111111111   3    0.30
111111111   4    0.00
111111111   5   -40.00
111111111   6   -200.00
111111111   7   -100.00
111111111   8   -0.50
111111111   9   -0.30
111111111   10   0.30
111111111   11   0.00
111111111   12  -40.00
111111111   13  -200.00
111111111   14  -100.00
400247129   1    NULL
400247129   2    NULL
400247129   3    NULL
400247129   4    NULL
400247129   5    NULL
400247129   6    NULL
400247129   7    NULL
400247129   8    0.00
400247129   9    15254.05
400247129   10   15254.05
400247129   11   15254.05
400247129   12   0.00
400247129   13   0.00
400247129   14   0.00
```

I would like to have the top 7 `SeqYears` from each `NumContr` row. Is there any clean away to achieve this result set?

The table name is tb_FinancialPosition

```
    111111111   8   -0.50
    111111111   9   -0.30
    111111111   10  0.30
    111111111   11  0.00
    111111111   12  -40.00
    111111111   13  -200.00
    111111111   14  -100.00
    400247129   8   0.00
    400247129   9   15254.05
    400247129   10  15254.05
    400247129   11  15254.05
    400247129   12  0.00
    400247129   13  0.00
    400247129   14  0.00
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is with variables:

```
SELECT NumContr, SeqYear, `check`
FROM (
  SELECT NumContr, SeqYear, `check`,
         @rn := IF(@num = NumContr, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@num := NumContr, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM tb_FinancialPosition
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @num := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY NumContr, SeqYear DESC) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 7
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d5bed/5)

In SQL Server it is easier to implement, since you have window functions:

```
SELECT NumContr, SeqYear, [check]
FROM (
   SELECT NumContr, SeqYear, [check],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NumContr 
                             ORDER BY SeqYear DESC) AS rn
   FROM tb_FinancialPosition) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 7
```

Comment: is this syntax legit on mysql server? although i declare the variables rn and num I get incorrect syntax error

Comment: @ArturPeniche Yes it should be OK. Have you checked the demo?

Comment: yes I've checked the demo and seems great, but somehow mysql server doesn't like := inside of a select

Comment: I'm so sorry, i gave wrong tag to the question, I'm working with MS SQL Server

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should be able to upvote you twice since I didn't knew about sqlfiddle. Sorry for the trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another way to do this

```
    select * from 
    (
      select * from 
      (
       select NumContr,SeqYear,`Check`
       from practise
       where NumContr ='111111111'
       order by SeqYear desc limit 7
      )t1 order by SeqYear asc 
    )table1


    Union all 

   select * from 
    (
      select * from 
     (
      select NumContr,SeqYear,`Check`
      from practise
      where NumContr ='400247129'
      order by SeqYear desc limit 7
     ) t2 order by SeqYear asc
   ) Table2
```

Comment: since i could have N different NumContr I would need to make N union all ? doesn't seem right

Comment: @ArturPeniche it's working fine as per your given table data that get order data in both NumContr case and make union them in a table.

Comment: sorry If I wasn't clear enough on my point. The problem I pointed out is if I have more than these two NumContr (f.e. 222222222) I will need to make another union all and so on

Comment: @ArturPeniche i answered your question as per given sample data....if you have dynamic data then query need to optimize